# Multiline file grep

Tags: ruby, grep, multiline

I have a file that has sections like this,

```
flags...id, description, used, color
AB, "Abandoned", 0, 13168840
DM, "Demolished", 0, 15780518
OP, "Operational", 0, 15780518...
```

where `...` represents a series of control characters e.g. ETX and STX. I am trying to grab multiple lines from the file.

I am using the following code:

```
f = File.open(somePath)
r = f.grep(/flags.+id, description, used, color(?<data>(?:.|\s)*?)[\x00-\x08]/)
```

This code does not work. I do not understand why. The documentation of grep appears to insinuate that the file is parsed line by line. I have a feeling that this may be the reason why the regular expression isn't returning any results.

1. Am I correct that grep uses line-by-line parsing? Is this why my regex isn't working as intended?
2. Would it be better to use `file.each_line` to capture the data?
3. Are there better/cleaner alternatives to all of the above?

Comment: You have not escaped the period `.`. You have to write `\.`.

Comment: @sawa, are you sure? Sancam says “where ... represents a series of control characters”. He doesn't look for periods, I think.

Comment: @Philicare I see. You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) comes to the rescue:

```
File.read('/path/to/file').scan(
  /flags.+id, description, used, color(?<data>(?:.|\s)*?)[\x00-\x08]/m
)
```

Comment: It appears that the problem is actually that I'm reading a binary file, it seems. I can use `File.binread("C:\\Users\\jwa\\Desktop\\TBD\\master.db")` to ensure I get the whole file, but still the regex doesn't seem to work... Oddly though, even scanning for `/./` returns no results... So that's confusing... xD Edit: Oops, my mistake `/./` does return matches.

Comment: Mind to share the file content? I believe explicit `File.binread().force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)` could help.

Comment: Sure https://ufile.io/rsakp. I also attempted using `enforce_encoding`, however it seems like it isn't a method on my old version of ruby (1.9.1).

Comment: Ruby 1.9.1? I wash my hands, sorry. BTW, the method name is `force_encoding`, not `enforce_encoding`.

Comment: Not entirely sure where I got the method name `enforce_encoding` from... xD And no problem! Thanks for trying to solve the issue though :)

Comment: FYI, your solution worked like a charm. My regex also had some issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable multiline mode. `.` doesn't match newlines by default.

From the documentation https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html

```
/./ - Any character except a newline.
/./m - Any character (the m modifier enables multiline mode)
```

Comment: but \s does match new lines by default. I don't think this is relevant. `m` as far as I know means each line is treated as it's own haystack such that `^` is the beginning of the line and `$` is the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct that grep uses line-by-line parsing?

Yes. Try on your file:

```
r = File.open(somePath) do |f|
  f.grep(/[A-Z]{2},/)
end

puts r
# => AB, "Abandoned", 0, 13168840
#    DM, "Demolished", 0, 15780518
#    OP, "Operational", 0, 15780518

puts r.inspect
# => ["AB, \"Abandoned\", 0, 13168840\n", "DM, \"Demolished\", 0, 15780518\n", "OP, \"Operational\", 0, 15780518\n"]
```

> Is this why my regex isn't working as intended?

Not only. What are you searching for, with [\x00-\x08]? An ascii or an hexadecimal character?

> Would it be better to use file.each_line to capture the data?

`File#grep` sounds good.

Comment: I mean the file does contain more than just the data structure. The file itself is 8000kb, but it's cool. I will try with a line-by-line method. Also What I'm scanning for, with the `[\x00-\x08]` is the control characters at the end of the section of text. It's not just a CSV file. It's an entire database file in a (undocumented) propriety database format.